# Plus ne réagisse / ne réagisse plus

Tags: sens, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans *L'École des cadavres* :

> Maîtres et valets s’en vont en gangrène, conjointement, les uns dans
> les autres, en fange,  en mélasse, sans qu’une seule fibre *plus ne
> réagisse*.

Y a-t-il une différence entre *plus ne réagisse* et *ne réagisse plus* ?

Comment: Ouais, un maître pour tout ce qui est nauséabonde....:)

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a aucune différence de sens.

C'est une tournure stylistique, la phrase « sonne mieux ».

> *Le sourire des Omphales, qui **plus ne bouge**,*
> *Et les yeux de Méduse ornent le timon rouge.*
> Emile Verhaeren, *L'ancien amour*, 1896

Attention, cette inversion ne se rencontre qu'à l'écrit, jamais à l'oral où elle serait très dure à comprendre.

Comment: Merci, mais il n'y a pas un effet particulier associé à cette tournure stylistique ?

Comment: Oui, un effet de style ;-)

Comment: Hahaha j'ai voulu dire un effet de sens

Comment: J'avais compris, mais pour moi il n'y a aucune différence de sens. C'est simplement la "musique" de la phrase qui motive cette inversion.